Is exposing mongo-db objectId to the front-end a real security problem?
I am currently building an e-commerce app with a cart stored in the localStorage.
To improve online payment security, I want to check the prices of my items in the backend before sending these prices to the payment platform.
The values of my items are not unique: some items can have the same value if they are in different categories.
That is the reasom I wanted to store ObjectId inside my cart (localStorage) and send all these objectIds to my backend to easily check the prices.
But I read that exposing database Id to the user is a bad practice.
My questions are: Is it really a bad practice ? Why ? How can do it differently without adding any complexity ?
Thanks for your help

An ObjectID contains 3 things:

time the ObjectID was created, in seconds since epoch
5-byte random value set when the process was started.  This is the process that created the ObjectID, usually the client/application machine
3-byte counter which is initialized to a random value, and is incremented for every ObjectID created by that client

An _id value in a MongoDB collection must be unique, so whether it contains an ObjectID or not, it uniquely identifies a single document in the collection.
Exposing the _id value in MongoDB is no more or less risky than exposing a unique primary key in any other database.
Exposing an ObjectID of any kind, not just in the _id field, leaks the creation time of that value.  Whether this is a problem will greatly depend on context.
If the potential problem is the timestamp contained in the ObjectID, use some other method to generate unique values to use in the _id field.

Thanks for your answer ! the creation time exposure is not really a problem in my case, so if it is the only problem it can generates, I will stay on this method
